# call constructor with instanciated superclass in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have this construct.

```
public class SuperClass{}
public class InheritedClass : SuperClass{}
```

I want my instantiated Superclass to become an InheritedClass instance.

```
var superClassInstance = new SuperClass();
InheritedClass inHeritInstance = new InheritedClass(superClassInstance) ;
```

Somebody told me, that will not work without setting all properties in the Constructor.
Is that correct?

Comment: Punch *somebody* into face! In `InheritedClass` constructor overload, which takes `SuperClass` parameter, you simply have to call base class overload which accept `SuperClass` parameter.

Comment: @Sinatr: A) I don't see such an overload mentioned here.  B) If the author writes one, he'll still need to set every property from the passed instance into the constructed instance.  C) Punching colleagues in the face is not productive.

Comment: @David, if OP wants what he wants, then he must to do something. Lets assume what he can change code. Sometimes programmers are allowed to change code. Then it's possible, see my answer.

Comment: @Sinatr: Your answer confirms what the OP's colleague stated, which is that the fields must be copied one at a time.  Note your use of `a = copy.a`, which is setting a field from the value in the original instance.  This line would have to be repeated for all fields, which is what the OP was asking to avoid if possible.  You are asserting that what the OP wants is possible, and demonstrating that it is not possible.  Programmers are allowed to change code, they're also allowed to be blatantly wrong.  You've demonstrated both.

Comment: @David, now I got it. You are right, I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want my instantiated Superclass to become an InheritedClass instance.

This is not possible. If you want it to be an instance of `InheritedClass` you must create one. You cannot upcast an instance of `SuperClass`.

Comment: By the way, that would not be what I would call "upcast". But you are right. Once an instance of a particular run-time type has been created, that instance retains the same run-time type. It can't be changed. He will have to use "hand-written" code to create a ***new*** instance of the desired type from the old instance (of the other type).

Answer (score 1):

That's true.. you can not Assign directly, In Constructor you have to transfer.

Instead..

you should create interface and implement the Interface into the class from where you are passing the value.

Now in into `InheritedClass` create constructor with the the interface as parameter, so whatever values are assigned into the First class, will be passed into `InheritedClass`

here you will have full access of First Class property.

Refer below dotnetfiddle url.

http://dotnetfiddle.net/8AgOCF

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. There is no inbuilt way to provide your own baseclass object to promote to subclass. Each subclass will build it's own baseclass before it calls the subclasses' constructor on it.

You will need to write your own constructor in the subclass that copies all relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, yes, I'm afraid that is correct.  A constructor is, by definition, creating a new instance.  So anything from an existing instance is going to have to be copied to the new instance.  It might be something like this:

```
public InheritedClass(SuperClass superClassInstance)
{
    // base fields
    Field1 = superClassInstance.Field1;
    Field2 = superClassInstance.Field2;
    Field3 = superClassInstance.Field3;

    // local fields
    Field4 = "some value";
    // etc.
}
```

Or you can split the work between the classes, something like this:

```
public SuperClass(superClassInstance)
{
    Field1 = superClassInstance.Field1;
    Field2 = superClassInstance.Field2;
    Field3 = superClassInstance.Field3;
}
```

then in the derived class:

```
public InheritedClass(superClassInstance)
    : base(superClassInstance)
{
    Field4 = "some value";
    // etc.
}
```

It gets a lot easier the other way around, creating a `SuperClass` from `InheritedClass`, since any instance of `InheritedClass` *is* an instance of `SuperClass` and can polymorphically be interpreted as such:

```
SuperClass someObject = inheritedClassInstance as SuperClass;
```

(Note that this would *not* be a "new instance" so watch out for reference errors.)  You *might* be able to do the same in reverse:

```
InheritedClass someObject = superClassInstance as InheritedClass;
```

But there is *no guarantee* that `superClassInstance` is also an instance of `InheritedClass` so you'd want to check for errors here.  And, again, this is not a new instance.

Using composition instead of inheritance you can potentially achieve your goal with less code.  For example, if you have a class like this:

```
public class InheritedClass
{
    public SuperClass BaseObject { get; private set; }
    // other fields
}
```

Then you can include a constructor in `InheritedClass` which just sets that one object:

```
public InheritedClass(SuperClass superClassInstance)
{
    BaseObject = superClassInstance;
}
```

Again, however, note that this is not a *new* instance of `SuperClass` in the property but a reference to the existing one.  To ensure a new one you'd still have to write your manual code (possibly in a `.Copy()` or `.Clone()` method on `SuperClass`?) to duplicate the instance.

In short, after all of my directionless brainstorming, cloning an instance field-by-field is going to require putting that field-by-field code *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here (a and b fields are for demo purposes):

```
public class SuperClass
{
    object a;
    public SuperClass()
    {
        a = "123";
    }
    // you need to have this
    public SuperClass(SuperClass copy)
    {
        a = copy.a;
    }
}

public class InheritedClass : SuperClass
{
    object b;
    public InheritedClass()
    {
        Init();
    }
    // and this
    public InheritedClass(SuperClass super): base(super)
    {
        // bacause you can't call base() and this()
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        b = "456";
    }
}
```

So you can do

```
var super = new SuperClass();
var inherited = new InheritedClass(super);
```

---

[Proof](http://dotnetfiddle.net/EOJWhM).

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, which can at least copy all the properties automatically.

```
public InheritedClass(SuperClass superClassInstance)
{
 foreach(var currentItem in superClassInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    GetType().GetProperty(currentItem.Name).SetValue(this,currentItem.GetValue(superClassInstance,null),null);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question as it only copies properties with a public setter and will therefore only work in very specific circumstances.

Comment: you are right. it only copies the properties but for that it is helpfull